# Overlapping rules in CSS - what is the true logic behind?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Consider the following:

```
<td class="datepickerDisabled"><a href="#"><span>12</span></a></td>
```

In my css, there are two rules that would match for this selector:

```
tbody.datepickerDays td:hover {
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

And the second one is:

```
td.datepickerDisabled:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
```

The second rule for setting `background-color` to `white` is not matched. I would think that would be the rule overriding the previous rule since it is more specific (cells with class `datepickerDisabled`).

Comment: 0,0,2,2 vs 0,0,2,1. The first one clearly wins.

Comment: would you mind to explain your answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"0,0,2,2 vs 0,0,2,1. The first one clearly wins."

```
tbody           Element      d
.datepickerDays Class        c
td              Element      d
:hover          Pseudo-class c
                              = 0,0,2,2

td                  Element      d
.datepickerDisabled Class        c
:hover              Pseudo-class c
                              = 0,0,2,1
```

If you do not understand this format, read http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity:

> A selector's specificity is calculated as follows:
>
> - count 1 if the declaration is from is a 'style' attribute rather than a rule with a selector, 0 otherwise (= a) (In HTML, values of an
>     element's "style" attribute are style sheet rules. These rules have no
>     selectors, so a=1, b=0, c=0, and d=0.)
> - count the number of ID attributes in the selector (= b)
> - count the number of other attributes and pseudo-classes in the selector (= c)
> - count the number of element names and pseudo-elements in the selector (= d) The specificity is based only on the form of the
>     selector. In particular, a selector of the form "[id=p33]" is counted
>     as an attribute selector (a=0, b=0, c=1, d=0), even if the id
>     attribute is defined as an "ID" in the source document's DTD.
>
> Concatenating the four numbers a-b-c-d (in a number system with a
>   large base) gives the specificity.

If you prefer a picture <sup>[source](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)</sup>:

[image]